# In ReactJS is there a way to filter rendered results that are being iterated over?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In AngularJS you can use "filter" to narrow down the results of an ng-repeat like so:

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: x">
```

Currently I am using Array.map() to render multiple items in an array in ReactJS and am wondering how exactly to replicate the functionality that Angular's ng-repeat filter has in ReactJS.

This is my current method I am using to render some blog posts:

```js
renderBlogs() {
      return this.props.blogs.map((blog) => {
        return (
          <div key={blog.id}>
            <Link to={`blogs/${blog.id}`}>
              <img src={blog.image_url} />
              <h1>Author</h1>
              <p>{blog.author}</p>
              <h1>Title</h1>
              <p>{blog.topic}</p>
            </Link>
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
```

Im hoping to just have an input field that filters the results of my iteration when the input field changes. Are there any NPM modules that could help with that or a typical approach to solving this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Map gives you a function per entry, so you could easily put some logic in the callback to only return the element if it passes your condition, or use _.filter.

Comment: Unlike other frameworks which shall remain unnamed, React encourages you to use JavaScript. You should consider learning the standard library of JS, in particular [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which will do (half of) what you want here. There's absolutely no reason to add another library into the mix. `lodash.filter` would be fine, but only if your input is `Object | Array` instead of being an array. You know this object is an array; no need to reach out to lodash.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Angular, React doesn't have its own primitives for doing things like that, and instead of reinventing the wheel, it just relies on JS.

In JavaScript, you can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) an array by calling `filter` and providing a function which will take each individual item and tell whether to include it or not:

```
[1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6].filter(x => x > 0) // [1, 3, 5]
```

Filter and map can also be combined:

```
[1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6].filter(x => x > 0).map(x => x * 2) // [2, 6, 10]
```

Nothing will change even if you return a React component from map, it's still the JS filter+map:

```
return this.props.blogs.filter(blog => {
  return true; // place your actual check here
}).map((blog) => {
  return (
    <div key={blog.id}>
      <Link to={`blogs/${blog.id}`}>
        <img src={blog.image_url} />
        <h1>Author</h1>
        <p>{blog.author}</p>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>{blog.topic}</p>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
})
```

Comment: I'm just curious about the performance, if the `blog` is a big object or `blogs` has too many items ?

Answer (score 0):

With React the solution requires more Javascript, but don't let this be a deterrent.

There are many ways that you could accomplish what you're after, but I think you should wire your text input to the state of your component or the state of your application using the `onChange` hook:

```
<input onChange={changeHandler} .. />
```

Implement your `changeHandler(..)` such that it calls `setState(..)` to update the model that stores your input text. This will re-render your component and child components, eventually calling your `renderBlogs(..)` function.

You will need to devise a predicate function that determines whether to display or hide a blog post based off of some criteria. I would abstract this into a helper function, but the implementation details are entirely up to you. You should probably base it off some combination of the text you have in your model and the `innerHTML` of the text elements in your markup.

Then I'd refactor the return statement of `renderBlogs(..)` to call this predicate before returning one of your Blog components.

```
renderBlogs() {
  return this.props.blogs.map((blog) => {
    return this.predicateFn(blog)
      ? this.renderBlog(blog)
      : null
  }).filter(Boolean);
}
```

I'd also recommend abstracting away the markup for your blog post into its own component or as a method on this component... something like `renderBlog(..)`.

Good luck!